# Dynamically loading posts causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

so I released my first Android app (COD Emeblem Tutorials) on the Google Play Store. I've been getting a lot of downloads but I noticed it's crashing when you scroll far enough down the dynamically loaded list.

The way I'm loading the tutorials in is by calling an API call to my website. Once the information returns I display an ImageView for each tutorial & have an async task go off to download the image as shown below. Whenever it reaches the 500th tutorial the app crashes with the errors below. I think it's saying the heap is out of memory. Any idea how I can prevent this from happening? Is this because I have too many ImageViews on the screen?

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    String id;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage, ProgressBar progressbar, String id) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        this.id = id;
        this.progressbar = progressbar;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            //Log.v("COD","doInBackground");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Image img = new Image(id, result);
        Brain.addImage(img);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}


> 11-10 19:11:59.952: E/dalvikvm-heap(1341): Out of memory on a 135440-byte allocation.
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=13 RUNNABLE
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4262ab40 self=0x5cf7ee20
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341):   | sysTid=1405 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1623637296
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=647 stm=148 core=0
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
11-10 19:11:59.952: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at com.codplayercards.codplayercards.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:30)
11-10 19:11:59.962: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at com.codplayercards.codplayercards.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:1)
11-10 19:11:59.962: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-10 19:11:59.962: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-10 19:11:59.962: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-10 19:11:59.962: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-10 19:11:59.962: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-10 19:11:59.962: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-10 19:11:59.962: D/skia(1341): --- decoder->decode returned false
11-10 19:11:59.962: W/dalvikvm(1341): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41830898)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at com.codplayercards.codplayercards.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:30)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at com.codplayercards.codplayercards.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:1)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-10 19:11:59.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     ... 4 more
11-10 19:12:00.103: D/AbsListView(1341): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-10 19:12:00.373: D/dalvikvm(1341): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 168K, 13% free 85864K/98208K, paused 127ms, total 132ms
11-10 19:12:00.373: I/dalvikvm-heap(1341): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 131776-byte allocation
11-10 19:12:00.513: D/dalvikvm(1341): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 13% free 85863K/98208K, paused 134ms, total 142ms
11-10 19:12:00.513: E/dalvikvm-heap(1341): Out of memory on a 131776-byte allocation.
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341): "AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=20 RUNNABLE
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42f01eb8 self=0x61ad5728
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341):   | sysTid=1532 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1637026936
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1051 stm=119 core=0
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
11-10 19:12:00.523: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at com.codplayercards.codplayercards.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:30)
11-10 19:12:00.533: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at com.codplayercards.codplayercards.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:1)
11-10 19:12:00.533: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-10 19:12:00.533: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-10 19:12:00.533: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-10 19:12:00.533: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-10 19:12:00.533: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-10 19:12:00.533: I/dalvikvm(1341):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-10 19:12:00.553: D/skia(1341): --- decoder->decode returned false
11-10 19:12:00.583: W/dalvikvm(1341): threadid=20: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41830898)
11-10 19:12:00.593: I/Process(1341): Sending signal. PID: 1341 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You can use the Google Volley library to download images and setup memory and disk caches according to this guide: http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

It's an excellent library that does all you need, plus it has an excellent caching, it's easy to use and you can use it anywhere in your code, from simple imageview to list (it recycles itself!).
Oh and also, their docs are outstanding !

Comment: Picasso is amazing! Thanks fixed my problem immediately. Now I only have one other problem - my app revolves around being able to click on the images. Is there a way I can either make the picasso imageview click through to the surrounding RelativeLayout or add an onclicklistener to the picasso image?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the images on to a listview?
If you are loading images on to a listview, consider only load the images that are needed.
If your images are way too big in resolution, consider sample down the size to a smaller resolution.
Lastly, make sure you recycle your bitmap for images that will move out of the visible scope.

If you have done all of the above, it should prevent you from getting out of memory error on android loading images.

If you want it easy, automatically handled image loading, you should consider using volley networkimageview as Eugen Pechanec suggested. Volley also have image caching ability which makes images loading a little faster on second try.